# Crash after updating to Fragment Testing library v1.1.0-alpha03

Tags: android, fragment, android-architecture-components, androidx, android-viewmodel

After updating to `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` v1.0-alpha03 we're now getting following crash at end of test.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Collection java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.values()' on a null object reference
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.clear(ViewModel.java:125)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore.clear(ViewModelStore.java:62)
```

Importantly this is test where we're mocking instance of `ViewModel` being used and issues seems to be related to associated changes to `lifecycle-viewmodel` v2.1.0-alpha01 which we now have a transitive dependency to.  Specifically crash is occurring in following method because `mBagOfTags` is null

```
final void clear() {
    mCleared = true;
    for (Object value: mBagOfTags.values()) {
        // see comment for the similar call in setTagIfAbsent
        closeWithRuntimeException(value);
    }
    onCleared();
}
```

Having worked through the issue, the title now is perhaps a little misleading.  The issue seems to be generally with mocking `ViewModel` instances since 2.1.0-alpha01 update

Comment: You should [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413132) with a sample project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake will try and get something minimal together that demonstrates the issue...in meantime could you comment on whether it should be possible in general to mock `ViewModel` instances with version that includes that `clear` method?

Comment: It wasn't an intentional break if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, definitely wasn't implying that....more a question about whether you might perhaps already be aware of issues mocking `ViewModel` with that release.

Comment: Nope, you're the very first person to experience it, hence why an issue and a sample project would be helpful in routing it to the right person :)

Comment: @ianhanniballake https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122273087 created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue boiled down, as mentioned, to not being able to mock `ViewModel` instances since at least `v2.1.0-alpha01` release.  The solution it turned out was to use `spy()` instead.  I'm using `Koin` so what that meant was that my test extends `KoinTest` now.  I can then add following to test

```
val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by inject()
```

and then call following

```
    val spySomeViewModel = spy(someViewModel)
    loadKoinModules(module {
        viewModel(override = true) {
            spySomeViewModel
        }
    })
```

and then, as was case when using `mock()` can do something like

```
doReturn(someResult).whenever(spySomeViewModel).someMethod()
```

**UPDATE:**
from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122273087
"We've fixed this internally in https://android-review.googlesource.com/863029 to ensure that mocked ViewModels work as before and this will be available in the next version of ViewModel (and Fragment, etc. that relies on it)."